# Android notification from service does not open activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, notifications, launch

Updated MyService @CommonsWare

i have a service that if started will set up an alarm that triggers the notification.

This works fine and the alarms are canceled if the service is stopped.

i am trying to get the notification to open a new activity class but can not get it done

my service class is the following:

```
   package com.example.andtip;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;


public class BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
   NotificationManager notificationManager;
   Notification myNotification;   

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, DoSomething.class);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,  new Intent("com.example.andtip"),0 );
    PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,  myIntent,0 );

        myNotification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
     .setContentTitle("This is a notification from the example alarm application.")
        .setContentText("Notification")      
        .setTicker("Notification!")
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
     .setContentIntent(pi)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)                
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .build();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

      }
}
```

how should i link the intent pi2 to the notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am trying to get the notification to open a new activity class but can not get it done

You are using `getBroadcast()` to create your `PendingIntent`. Use `getActivity()` to create a `PendingIntent` that starts up an activity. Make sure that the `Intent` you put in the `PendingIntent` is for an activity, and make sure that the activity has its entry in the manifest.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare i changed the getbroadcast to getactivity and added an intent(context, dosometing.class) now as soon as trigger goes off the activity opens but i dont get the notification anymore (wanted to click it before the new activity opens)

Comment: @IngolfKrauss: You have two different `PendingIntent`s that you are using. One is for the alarm. That should trigger a `BroadcastReceiver` that displays the `Notification`. The second `PendingIntent` is the one you use in the `Notification` itself. *That* is the one that should be a `getActivity()` `PendingIntent`.

Comment: thanks again for the hint i updated the post and changed broadcast receiver and added the getactivity pending intent, how is it linked with the notification?

Comment: @IngolfKrauss: You pass the `getActivity()` `PendingIntent` to `setContentIntent()`.

Comment: It looks to me that you should change setcontent intent to pi2 and it will work.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks alot i did not now that you can pass a second pending intent in a pending intent. it works fine

Comment: @domink4142 thanks alot i did not now that you can pass a second pending intent in a pending intent. it works fine